# Add multiple columns in a datagrid WPF c#

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I am new in WPF C#, I am trying to build a WPF datagrid in C#, I want to add the colomns from a List like the dfollowing code:

```
private void addColumn1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        List<String> headers = new List<string>();
        headers.Add("URC");
        headers.Add("Inv Ini ECP");
        headers.Add("Inv Ini RCSA");
        headers.Add("Inv Fin ECP");
        headers.Add("Inv Fin RCSA");
        headers.Add("Entradas ECP");
        headers.Add("Entradas RCSA");
        headers.Add("Salidas ECP");
        headers.Add("Salidas RCSA");
        headers.Add("Prod ECP");
        headers.Add("Prod RCSA");
        headers.Add("Tran A ECP");
        headers.Add("Tran A RCSA");
        headers.Add("Bal ECP");
        headers.Add("Bal RCSA");
        headers.Add("Tot Inv Ini");
        headers.Add("Tot Inv Fin");
        headers.Add("Tot Entra");
        headers.Add("Tot Cargas");
        DataGridTextColumn textColumn = new DataGridTextColumn();

        for (int j=0; j < headers.Count; j++)
        {

            textColumn.Header = headers[j];
            textColumn.Binding = new Binding("TotBal");
            AcumProp.Columns.Add(textColumn);
        }
```

But I am getting an error on the line `AcumProp.Columns.Add(textColumn);` There is a different way to do this? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're adding the same column object over and over. You need to move the `new DataGridTextColumn()` line inside the loop. By the way, don't ever say you got an error without saying *what* error. People have to guess then. Help us help you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new `DataGridTextColumn` for each column you want to add, i.e.:

```
...
headers.Add("Tot Entra");
headers.Add("Tot Cargas");

for (int j=0; j < headers.Count; j++)
{
    DataGridTextColumn textColumn = new DataGridTextColumn();
    textColumn.Header = headers[j];
    textColumn.Binding = new Binding("TotBal");
    AcumProp.Columns.Add(textColumn);
}
```